# Maximize integral over line

Tags: integration, geometry, optimization

I have three points in 2D space, $a$ and $p_0$, $p_1$. There's a line between $p_0$ and $p_1$ over which I'd like to integrate
$$
I(y) = \int_{p_0}^{p_1} \langle y, a - x\rangle^2 \; \text{d}x
$$
with some arbitrary $y\in\mathbb{R}^2$.

Which *normalized* $y$ maximizes the integral?

Comment: Hint: Differentiate under the integral sign

Comment: With respect to $y_1$, $y_2$? Why?

Comment: Well, the general thought is that you want to maximize a sufficiently smooth function $I:[0,1]\cross[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. One usually does that with calculus right?

Comment: Why can I exchange integration and differentiation though?

Comment: I will refer you to  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 2):

Write $y=(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ and differentiate with respect to $\theta$. You get (please check!):

$$
{dI\over d\theta}=
\cos2\theta\int_{p_0}^{p_1}2(a_1-x_1)(a_2-x_2)\, dl
-\sin2\theta\int_{p_0}^{p_1} \big((a_1-x_1)^2-(a_2-x_2)^2\big)\, dl.
$$
That vanishes if
$$
\tan2\theta=
{\int_{p_0}^{p_1} 2(a_1-x_1)(a_2-x_2)\, dl
\over
\int_{p_0}^{p_1}\big((a_1-x_1)^2-(a_2-x_2)^2\big)\, dl
}.
$$